# @EmbeddedId with autogenerated id using @GenerateValue, this mix doesn't works as needed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I am trying to work with @EmbeddedId, this is my code as follows,

```
create table TBL_EMPLOYEE_002(
  ID integer generated always as identity (start with 100,increment by 10), 
  COUNTRY varchar(50),
  NAME varchar(50),
  constraint PK_EMP_00240 primary key(ID,COUNTRY)
)
```

The Embedded class as follows,

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeIdTwo implements Serializable{
     public EmployeeIdTwo(){}
    public EmployeeIdTwo(String country){
        this.empCountry = country;
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name="ID") 
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Column(name="COUNTRY",length=50)
    private String empCountry;

// implementation of hashCode and equals and only getters 
...
}
```

employee Entity as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEE_002")
public class EmployeeEntitySix implements Serializable{

    public EmployeeEntitySix(){}
    public EmployeeEntitySix(EmployeeIdTwo id,String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.employeeName = name;
    }

    @EmbeddedId    
    private EmployeeIdTwo id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String employeeName;

// getters and setters
}
```

this is the code written in main method,

```
private static void storVal(EntityManager em){
    EmployeeEntitySix employee = new EmployeeEntitySix(new EmployeeIdTwo("KENYA"), "Henry Olaanga");
    em.persist(employee);
}
```

but once i run an above code i get an exception as follows,

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Attempt to modify an identity column 'ID'.
```

Can you please let me know where i am getting wrong,
if my EmbeddedId class contain an autogenerated column, than what should be the approach.

Just to know I am using hibernate as persistence provider and JPA as persistence API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you would not be asking this question if `Id` could easily and uniquely identify an employee.  If you have the ability to modify your tables, I'd suggest either making `Id` reliably unique, or adding an auto-generated `UniqueId` column.

Some of these kinds of errors actually come from the DB schema, and not from JPA/Hibernate.  If you're trying to update a column that the DB doesn't have a generation strategy for, this might be what is causing your error.

You might also have a look at [autoincrement id is not reflecting in composite key using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813755/autoincrement-id-is-not-reflecting-in-composite-key-using-jpa), as I think this covers what you are asking about.