# Creating a composite Primary Key with a unique string and sequential, corresponding number

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate, and am struggling with a way to create a composite Primary Key that uses both a unique string an auto-incrementing (sequentially, according to the unique string) long. I have found some resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701576/embeddedid-with-autogenerated-id-using-generatevalue-this-mix-doesnt-works-a) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813755/autoincrement-id-is-not-reflecting-in-composite-key-using-jpa), but am still having trouble.

**I am using Java 8, Hibernate 5, Spring Boot 1.5, and Spring JDBC 5 and MySQL connector 6, with MySQL 5.7**

### Problem

I am trying to create an Primary Key for an entity that maps to a ticketing table. I want the Primary Key to be something like `PROJ-1` which I have seen in a lot of places and I like the convention.

Ideally, I would like there to be two parts to the PK. I want a unique, project code like `PROJ` and a ticket number that increments with that project code, each ticket should be sequential: `PROJ-1` `PROJ-2` `PROJ-3` but if I make another project code like `TICK` then it should start from one: `TICK-1` `TICK-2` and so on. Instead of having entries like `PROJ-1` `PROJ-2` `PROJ-3` `TICK-4` and `TICK-5`.

I am not sure how to accomplish this with hibernate.

The code I have so far is this.

### Entity

**UPDATE 2** Made the generated TicketIdentifier unique.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "support_ticket")
public class SupportTicket implements Serializable {
    private TicketIdentifier id;
    ... other irrelevant properties

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(unique = true, nullable = false))
    public TicketIdentifier getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(TicketIdentifier id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    ... other irrelevant getters and setters
}
```

### Embeddable Class

**UPDATE** Changed ticket number to a non-unique value, per the comments.

**UPDATE 2** Made project non-unique, and did it from the ticket-side

```
@Embeddable
public class TicketIdentifier implements Serializable {
    String projectId;
    Long ticketNum;

    public TicketIdentifier() {}

    public TicketIdentifier(String projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @Column(name = "project", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(String projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ticket", nullable = false)
    public Long getTicketNum() {
        return ticketNum;
    }

    public void setTicketNum(Long ticketNum) {
        this.ticketNum = ticketNum;
    }
    ... implementing of hashcode and equals
}
```

### Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE support_ticket
(
  project         VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL,
  ticket          BIGINT       NOT NULL,
  ... irrelevant stuff
  PRIMARY KEY (project, ticket),
  CONSTRAINT UK_6qwbkx66syjgp0jcxn16vkqkd
)
```

But as you can see the ticket is merely a `bigint` instead of looking more like `bigint auto_increment` not sure what I am doing wrong here. This is very close to what I think I would like. Except the ticket should auto-increment (as detailed in the "problem" section), and I don't know how (or if this is the right place) to put a dash between the project and ticket column combination.

Additionally, in the below screenshot, I am also unable to do two things: automatically increment the value of `ticket` and, re-use the same project code. I can see in the DDL that the latter is because project has to be unique, but I want it to be a *unique combination* only.

[image: Error when trying to insert data]

### UPDATE

I was able to get the combination unique (I think), but am still unable automatically increment the value of `ticket` the way I want.

Any suggestions on how to do this in Java and/or Hibernate combos would be much appreciated. Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: I think this might help you out : 
https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/

Comment: You don't want `ticketNum` to be unique: there can be both a PROJ-1 ticket and a TICK-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use a custom generation strategy for your primary key. (Note that `@GeneratedValue` can only be used with `@Id` annotation)

To implement a custom generation strategy you need to create a class that implements the `IdentifierGenerator` interface or extends one of the existing generators, for example, [SequenceStyleGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/SequenceStyleGenerator.html). Then you can define it using `@GenericGenerator` annotation:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ticket", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "custom-sequence",
    strategy = "your.package.CustomGenerator"
)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-sequence")
public String getTicketNum() {
    return ticketNum;
}
```

To demonstrate by example, I've modified your `SupportTicket` entity in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "support_ticket")
public class SupportTicket implements Serializable {

    private String projectId;
    private String ticketNum;

    public SupportTicket() {
    }

    public SupportTicket(String projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @Column(name = "project", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(String projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ticket", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "custom-sequence",
            strategy = "your.package.CustomGenerator"
    )
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-sequence")
    public String getTicketNum() {
        return ticketNum;
    }

    public void setTicketNum(String ticketNum) {
        this.ticketNum = ticketNum;
    }
}
```

The `ticket` column now is a primary key that will hold values like `PROJ-1` and `TICK-1` generated by the `CustomGenerator`. So I've changed the column type to `VARCHAR`.

The last step is to implement the `CustomGenerator`. As you are using MySQL, and it doesn't have sequences, you have to emulate them.

```
public class CustomGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    @Override
    public synchronized Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof SupportTicket) {
            String sequenceName = ((SupportTicket) obj).getProjectId();
            Serializable result = null;
            try {
                Connection c = session.connection();
                Statement s = c.createStatement();
                s.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sequences\n" +
                        "     (\n" +
                        "         name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n" +
                        "         next INT NOT NULL\n" +
                        "     );");
                s.execute("INSERT INTO sequences (name, next)\n" +
                        "VALUES ('" + sequenceName + "', @current := 1)\n" +
                        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \n" +
                        "next = @current := next + 1");
                ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery("SELECT @current");
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    int nextValue = resultSet.getInt(1);
                    result = sequenceName + "-" + nextValue;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This custom generator will create a `sequences` table where each row corresponds to a specific `projectId` and use it to increment the `ticketNum` field.

**UPDATE:** It is also possible to create an entity for the `sequences` table and use the hibernate session to manage it:

```
@Override
public synchronized Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof SupportTicket) {
        Session s = (Session) session;
        String sequenceName = ((SupportTicket) obj).getProjectId();
        Sequences sequences = (Sequences) s.get(Sequences.class, sequenceName);
        long next = 1;
        if (sequences == null) {
            sequences = new Sequences(sequenceName, next);
        } else {
            next = sequences.getNext() + 1;
            sequences.setNext(next);
        }
        s.saveOrUpdate(sequences);
        return sequenceName + "-" + next;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` to your properties to force hibernate to create a new table if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This gets me really close, but I am using MySQL instead of Postgres. Can you update your answer of how to create a sequence for MySQL? Also it looks like `SequenceGenerator` is deprecated so I've used `SequenceStyleGenerator` which has a generate method exactly how you've shown, but you might update that too.

Comment: @mrClean Thanks for the feedback! I've updated my answer according to MySQL syntax. MySQL doesn't have sequences, but that's not a problem - you can create a table and store all incremented values in it.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that is what I'm looking for! There's no way to move that table create statement to an entity and let hibernate manage it, is there? That'd be a bonus for cleanliness, but I could probably understand if that's not possible. I'll go ahead and mark this as complete though, as it solved my problem.

Comment: @mrClean Yes, it is possible. Check my update. But you should test it

Comment: Perfect, that really cleans it up. Thanks for your help, I'll be sure to test. I've upvoted your answer +1 for such a clean solution.

Comment: @mrClean Thank you! I was glad to help